# DDD: how to properly implement with JPA/Hibernate entities relation?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

If we follow DDD principles, one aggregate root should have only references (by id) to another aggregate root(s).

Example:

```
// Product Aggregate root
class Product { 

   // References to categories Aggregate Roots (to ids)
   Set<Long> categoryIds;
}
```

But how can it be achieved with JPA/Hibernate?
In jpa, if we want to have, for example, OneToMany relation, we defined it as follow:

```
// Product Aggregate root
class Product { 

   // Holds category aggregate roots
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   Set<Category> categories;
}
```

So JPA-s approach will hold category aggregate roots itself, which is not recommended in DDD.

How would you design relations with JPA but to fit DDD principles?

P.S.: I was thinking to make `categories` property of string type and hold comma separated list of category ids, but is there any better solution?

Comment: `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` is heading in the wrong direction, because that ties the two aggregates to the same transaction

Answer (score 5):

It’s a good question, but your example is not applicable. Logically a ***Category*** is not part of a ***Product*** Aggregate Root. Both ***Product*** and ***Category*** have global IDs. When you delete a ***Product***, you would not delete the ***Categories*** that it belongs to and when you delete a ***Category*** you would not delete all the ***Products*** that it has.

A page that summarizes Aggregates usage from [Eric Evans's DDD book](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=hHBf4YxMnWMC&lpg=PA128&pg=PA128#v=onepage&q&f=false) is available for free at Google Books. Here is what it says about Aggregates:

> • The root ENTITY has global identity and is ultimately responsible
> for checking invariants.
>
> • Root ENTITIES have global identity.
> ENTITIES inside the boundary have local identity, unique only within
> the AGGREGATE.
>
> • Nothing outside the AGGREGATE boundary can hold a
> reference to anything inside, except to the root ENTITY. The root
> ENTITY can hand references to the internal ENTITIES to other objects,
> but those objects can use them only transiently, and they may not hold
> on to the reference. The root may hand a copy of a VALUE OBJECT to
> another object, and it doesn't matter what happens to it, because it's
> just a VALUE and no longer will have any association with the
> AGGREGATE.
>
> • As a corollary to the previous rule, only AGGREGATE
> roots can be obtained directly with database queries. All other
> objects must be found by traversal of associations.
>
> • Objects within
> the AGGREGATE can hold references to other AGGREGATE roots.
>
> • A delete operation must remove everything within the AGGREGATE boundary at
> once. (With garbage collection, this is easy. Because there are no
> outside references to anything but the root, delete the root and
> everything else will be collected.)
>
> • When a change to any object> within the AGGREGATE boundary is committed, all invariants of the whole AGGREGATE must be satisfied.

Regarding the JPA implementation I would say that multiple approaches would work:

1. `@Embeddable` seems like a bulletproofed solution because the constituents will not have IDs.
2. `@OneToMany, @JoinTable`, etc. - also works as far as you don't reference constituents by IDs from other entities. This needs to be insured during implementation though, and can be violated accidentally.

Comment: Alex Evans? Do you mean [Eric Evans](https://twitter.com/ericevans0)?

Comment: Yes, a typo, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a join table to avoid the categories aggregating the roots like this:

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable
    private Set<Category> categories;

    // constructor, getters, setters, etc...
}


@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    // constructor, getters, setters, etc...
}
```

Just as an example I'll plug a few together:

```
for (int n = 0; n < 3; ++n) {
    categoryRepository.save(new Category());
}

Set<Category> categories = categoryRepository.findAll();

productRepository.save(new Product(categories));
```

Which results in the following (you didn't specify your DBMS, so I just assumed...) MySQL:

```
MariaDB [so41336455]> show tables;
+----------------------+
| Tables_in_so41336455 |
+----------------------+
| category             |
| product              |
| product_categories   |
+----------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [so41336455]> describe category; describe product; describe product_categories;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| product_id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| categories_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And of course no surprise with respect to their content:

```
MariaDB [so41336455]> select * from category; select * from product; select * from product_categories;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+------------+---------------+
| product_id | categories_id |
+------------+---------------+
|          1 |             1 |
|          1 |             2 |
|          1 |             3 |
+------------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Also I would avoid storing relations in a comma-separated list when you're using a relational database. It leads to unhealthy database design and will cause you headaches at some point.

Comment: But again, `Product` holds a set of `Category`s. That's what we should avoid in the first place according to DDD.

Comment: Yes, 'Category' in this case should be just CategoryId

Answer (score 0):

It's best to stick with referencing by identity when navigating between aggregates. Use a service to load required objects before calling aggregate behavior. For example:

```
public class MyProductApplicationService {
    ...
    @Transactional
    public void loadDependentDataAndCarryOutAggregateAction(Long productId, Long categoryId) {

        Product product = productRepository.findOne(productId);
        Category category = categoryRepository.findOne(categoryId);

        product.doActionThatNeedsFullCategoryAndMayModifyProduct(category);
    }
}
```

If that is too cumbersome, then at least do not span transactions from one aggregate to another:

```
class Product {

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
   Set<Category> categories;
}

public class Category {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "productid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Product product;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but in the first approach, where will you store categories references for product?

Comment: @moreo Just add `@Column private Long productId` to the `Category`